# Add custom column with User total spent in woocommerce admin orders

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, orders

I want to add a column with Customer Total Spent, but I want the sum of users and guest customer. The function Get_total_spent is by registered Customer, i want the guest too.

This is the code that I have:

```
add_filter( 'manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'bbloomer_add_another_order_admin_list_column' );
 
function bbloomer_add_another_order_admin_list_column( $columns ) {
    $columns['total_spent'] = 'Historical Spent';
    return $columns;
}
 
add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', 'bbloomer_add_another_order_admin_list_column_content' );
 
function bbloomer_add_another_order_admin_list_column_content( $column ) {
   
    global $post;
 
    if ( 'total_spent' === $column ) {
 
        $order = wc_get_order( $post->ID );
        $user_id = (int)$order->user_id;
        $customer = new WC_Customer( $user_id );
        echo $customer->get_total_spent();
      
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello.  When you say, "i want the guest too." - what have you tried in an effort to even tackle this question?

Comment: I want the total spent of registered users and not registered users (people that buy as guest and dont create an user in my ecommerce). For example, in the Customer Report of woocommerce they show us Both registered customers and guests, if a guest checks out using the same email address more than once, their orders will be associated with each other (and they will be considered the same purchaser). But when I use the function get_customer_total_spent it show information of registered users only.

Comment: Howard's question is, what have you tried to modify the `get_total_spent()` function to work for guests as well, and where did you get stuck in that process? 
it looks like you didn't read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) page before posting your question, where you can read the following: _"don't ask about questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)"_